# Event wrapper Android - How to clear the first observer?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I'm reading a lot about that, but I can't find a solution. I've never used before MutableLiveDate and I found out the event wrapper approch, but I'm finding some problem to use it.
The code below works fine when I click button only one time, but for some reason I have to press button twice I recieve a NullPointerException.
Creating two separate observers works. But on the same, repeated several times it passes me a null value in the getContentIfNotHandled()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.montaggioapp.montaggio.model.ReturnCode.getReturnCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.montaggioapp.montaggio.InCorsoActivity$2.onChanged(InCorsoActivity.java:147)
        at com.example.montaggioapp.montaggio.InCorsoActivity$2.onChanged(InCorsoActivity.java:143)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:468)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:425)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:205)
        at com.example.montaggioapp.montaggio.InCorsoActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$com-example-montaggioapp-montaggio-InCorsoActivity(InCorsoActivity.java:164)
        at com.example.montaggioapp.montaggio.InCorsoActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onChanged(Unknown Source:6)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class InCorsoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener<Causale>{

    private static final String MY_PREFS = "SAVE_VALUE";
    private static final String MY_CONFIG = "VALUE_CONFIG";
    private SharedPreferences prefs,config;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private InCorsoViewModel inCorsoViewModel;
    ActivityInCorsoBinding binding;
    Observer<Event<ReturnCode>> eventRC_DatiLav, eventRC_Conferma;
    private SpinnerAdapter adapter;
    private String pin, ordPro;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_corso);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
        config = getSharedPreferences(MY_CONFIG,MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        inCorsoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(InCorsoViewModel.class);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_in_corso);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.setInCorso(inCorsoViewModel);
        binding.qtaProdotte.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        binding.qtaProdotte.requestFocus();

        List<SpinnerViewModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(CausaleMapper.map(new Causale("SEL. CAUSALE"), (OnClickListener<Causale>) this));
        items.add(CausaleMapper.map(new Causale("FINE LAV"), (OnClickListener<Causale>) this));
        items.add(CausaleMapper.map(new Causale("PAUSA"), (OnClickListener<Causale>) this));
        items.add(CausaleMapper.map(new Causale("SOSPESO"), (OnClickListener<Causale>) this));

        String serverName = config.getString("serverName","");
        String port = config.getString("port","");
        String schemaOrion = config.getString("schemaOrion","");
        pin= prefs.getString("pin","0") ;
        ordPro = prefs.getString("ordPro","0");
        String baseurl = "http://"+serverName+":"+port+"/ords/"+schemaOrion;

        eventRC_DatiLav = new Observer<Event<ReturnCode>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Event<ReturnCode> returnCodeEvent) {
                ReturnCode returnCode = returnCodeEvent.getContentIfNotHandled();
                int rc = returnCode.getReturnCode();
                if (rc < 0 ){
                    String msg = returnCode.getReturnMessage();
                    message(msg, new Cb() {
                        @Override
                        public void onOkCliked() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelezionaAttActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                   String[] strDatiLav = returnCode.getReturnMessage().split(";");
                   binding.OrdineInCorso.setText(strDatiLav[0]);
                   binding.codParteInCorso.setText(strDatiLav[1]);
                   binding.desParteInCorso.setText(strDatiLav[2]);
                   binding.PezziOrdInCorso.setText(strDatiLav[3]);
                   binding.PezziProdInCorso.setText(strDatiLav[4]);
                   binding.StatoInCorso.setText(prefs.getString("stato"," "));
                   binding.inDateInCorso.setText(getCurrentDate());
                   adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_view, BR.viewModel,items);
                   binding.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
        };
        //inCorsoViewModel.makeApiDatiLavCall(ordPro);
        inCorsoViewModel.makeApiDatiLavCall(ordPro,baseurl);
        inCorsoViewModel.getLiveDataApiDatiLav().observe(this,eventRC_DatiLav);




        inCorsoViewModel.getDataOra(binding).observe(this, inCorso -> {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(inCorso).getStrDate())) {
                binding.inDateInCorso.setError("Data non selezionata");
                binding.inDateInCorso.requestFocus();
            }
            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(inCorso).getStrTime())) {
                binding.inTimeInCorso.setError("Orario non selezionato");
                binding.inTimeInCorso.requestFocus();
            }

            else {


                eventRC_Conferma = new Observer<Event<ReturnCode>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(Event<ReturnCode> returnCodeEvent) {
                        ReturnCode returnCode = returnCodeEvent.getContentIfNotHandled();
                        int rc = returnCode.getReturnCode();
                        if (rc < 0 ){
                            String msg = returnCode.getReturnMessage();
                            message(msg, () -> {

                            });
                        }else {
                            String msg = returnCode.getReturnMessage();
                            messageEseguito(msg, () -> {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SelezionaAttActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
                inCorsoViewModel.makeApiCall(pin,ordPro,baseurl);
                inCorsoViewModel.getLiveData().observe(this,eventRC_Conferma);



            }
        });

        binding.btnAnnulaInCorso.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        });

    }
```

ViewModel class

```
private MutableLiveData<Event<ReturnCode>> liveDataApiCall;

@Inject
ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Inject
public InCorsoViewModel(){
    this.liveDataApiCall = new MutableLiveData<>();
    
}



@Override
public MutableLiveData<Event<ReturnCode>> getLiveData() {
    return liveDataApiCall;
}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void makeApiCall(String pin, String ordPro,String baseurl) {
        String tipoMov = prefs.getString("tipoMov","");
        String idMac = "";
        String dataOra = date.getValue()+" "+time.getValue();
        String quant = qta.getValue() != null  ? qta.getValue() : "0";
        String param = "";

        AggOrdRepo aggOrdRepo = new AggOrdRepo(apiInterface);
        aggOrdRepo.getAggiornaOrdine(baseurl,pin,ordPro,tipoMov,idMac,dataOra,quant,param,liveDataApiCall,toastMessageObserver);
    }
```

Repository class

```
 private Disposable disposable;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private MutableLiveData<Event<ReturnCode>> liveDataApiDatiLav;
    private MutableLiveData<String> toastMessageObserver;

    public DatiLavRepo(ApiInterface apiInterface){
        this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
    }

    public void getDatiLav(String baseurl, String ordPro, MutableLiveData<Event<ReturnCode>> liveDataApiDatiLav, MutableLiveData<String> toastMessageObserver){
        String HTTPS_PATH_GETORD = null;

        try {
            HTTPS_PATH_GETORD = baseurl+"/gm/montaggio?p_cmd=3&p_p1="+ URLEncoder.encode(ordPro,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        this.liveDataApiDatiLav = liveDataApiDatiLav;
        this.toastMessageObserver = toastMessageObserver;



        disposable = apiInterface.getDatiLavorazione(HTTPS_PATH_GETORD)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::handlerResponse,this::handlerError);
     
    }

    private void handlerResponse(ReturnCode rc) {
        liveDataApiDatiLav.postValue(new Event(rc));
    }

    private void handlerError(Throwable t) {
        toastMessageObserver.setValue("Something unexpected happened to our request: "+t.getMessage());
    }


public class EventObserver<T> implements Observer<Event<T>> {
    private OnEventChanged onEventChanged;

    public EventObserver(OnEventChanged onEventChanged) {
        this.onEventChanged = onEventChanged;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Event<T> tEvent) {
        if (tEvent != null && tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled() != null && onEventChanged != null)
            onEventChanged.onUnhandledContent(tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled());

    }

    interface OnEventChanged<T> {
        void onUnhandledContent(T data);
    }
}

public class Event<T> {
    private boolean hasBeenHandled = false;
    private T content;

    public Event(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public T getContentIfNotHandled() {
        if (hasBeenHandled) {
            return null;
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true;
            return content;
        }
    }

    public boolean isHandled() {
        return hasBeenHandled;
    }

}
```

If anyone can help me understand how this works

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't provided the full code, so I'll try to help you using the snippets you provided.

This error happens, because `returnCode` which you get in this line `ReturnCode returnCode = returnCodeEvent.getContentIfNotHandled();` is `null`. It means that `returnCodeEvent.getContentIfNotHandled()` returns `null`.

Therefore, judging by the code of your `Event` class, its `getContentIfNotHandled()` returns value only once.

So all above information leads us to the conclusion that some observer gets value from your Event before it comes to the observer from your `Activity`.

From the snippets you provided I see only one thing that can lead your program to this error. It is your class `EventObserver`:

```
public class EventObserver<T> implements Observer<Event<T>> {
    private OnEventChanged onEventChanged;

    public EventObserver(OnEventChanged onEventChanged) {
        this.onEventChanged = onEventChanged;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Event<T> tEvent) {
        if (tEvent != null && tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled() != null && onEventChanged != null) // Here you call tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled() event FIRST TIME, so the value is picked
        
onEventChanged.onUnhandledContent(tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled()); // It's the SECOND TIME when you called tEvent.getContentIfNotHandled(), so it will be null.

    }

    interface OnEventChanged<T> {
        void onUnhandledContent(T data);
    }
}
```

**In `onChanged()` method you're calling `Event.getContentIfNotHandled()` twice, so probably this is the problem part of your code.** I'm almost sure that by fixing this you will fix your problem, so you can debug this place carefully and fix this error.

Comment: when I called tEvent the second time there is the old data. How can I reset data?